# Pass Query String Parameters to WebService Using $.ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web-services

If I have a webservice that needs several querystring parameters in order to query the underlying DB, should I place them in the URL or can I place them into a variable which is then passed to the data parameter of the $.ajax request? Part of my question is simply - What exactly does the data parameter represent?

In the snippet below, targetURL is successfully passed in as the URL. However, when I try and passing 'parameters' as the data parameter(data: parameters), the call fails.

```js
    function JSONTest() {

        //var targetURL = "http://localhost:49633/compass/compatability/webservices/SearchDatabase.ashx?mode=contact&searchvalue=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("jsonInput").value) + "&format=json";
        var targetURL = "http://localhost:49633/compass/compatability/webservices/SearchDatabase.ashx";
        var parameters = "mode=contact&searchvalue=da&format=json";

        document.getElementById("targetURL1").innerText = targetURL;
        document.getElementById("ResultTable").innerHTML = "";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //rest Type
            url: targetURL,
            data: parameters,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                jsonResponse = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                for (i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        createTableRow(i, "tableRow");
                    } else {
                        createTableRow(i, "tableRowAlternating");
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("ReturnTest2").style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: The data property is what is sent to server....but you are mixing urlencoded string and json contentType....so what type are you actually expecting to receive at server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want json sent as your contentType implies then you need to change your data from urlencoded string to json by starting with an object then stringifying that object

```
var data = {
   mode: 'contact',
   searchvalue: 'da',
   format: 'json'
}
var parameters = JSON.stringify(data);
```

If you are expecting standard form encoded data at server then remove:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Also never ever use `async: false,` it is deprecated and has always been a terrible practice

Comment: So then data is used to send JSON to the server and if I need to send parameters via QueryString, I should place them in the URL?

Comment: not if you use `GET` , jquery would put them in url for you. Also the default for send data in pot is not json it is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*

Comment: Is this correct?
{mode:"contact",searchvalue:"da",format:"json"} is not converted to the querystring parameters and is not the equivalent of mode=contact&searchvalue=da&format=json

Comment: it would be if using GET not POST. You should probably read the manual http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/